# WPF) How can I Minimize pened window by ShowDialog without parent window's location change

Tags: c#, wpf

I need your help.

I made a simple program that have two windows.(WindowA, WindowB)
WindowB is opened by ShowDialog() when click a button on WindowA.
And WindowB has a button that can minimize WindowB itself.

`private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized; }`

When I click minimizeButton, WindowB is minimized well But WindowA is sent to the back of the windows.
Forexample, Chrome window is opened and my program(WindowA, WindowB) is opened on th Chrome window. But when click the minimizeButton on WindowB, WindowB is minimized and WindowA go to behind of Chrome window.

I think it is because of WindowB is opened by ShowDialog().
I want WindowA don't move when minimize WindowB.

How can I do?

Thank you

Comment: You are not supposed to minimize a dialog window. Use `Show()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick in WindowB.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    ShowDialog();
}
```